# can 'a' come before most

Tags: articles

I think the following sentence is incorrect

> Leena is a most intelligent student.

because in such constructions **the** must come before **most**

But I found this sentence in a book.

I think it should be

> Leena is **the** most intelligent student.

or even better way to write this will be

> Leena is the most intelligent student in the class.

Comment: They are both possible and natural. It depends on the context, and what you're trying to say. There is no rule that it must be **a** or **the**.

Comment: Most can mean 'very'; this is a most delicious cake.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All three sentences are grammatically correct, but there are different meanings.

Saying someone is "a most intelligent student" compliments their intelligence, but does not compare them to any specific group of other students.

Saying someone is "the most intelligent..." implies there is a specific group out of which this student is more intelligent than any others in the group.